# Boost-graph,accessing un-bundled vertex/edge properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

[This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) boost documentation describes how to define bundled and non bundled properties for the vertices and edges of a graph. However it is missing how to set/get unbundlede properties.

How can I access an integer and a string properties if I am using non bundled properties defined like this:

```
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> EdgeWeightProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
      boost::vecS,
      boost::directedS,
      boost::property<int, string>,
      EdgeWeightProperty> Graph;
```

Thanks!